# Is the tag synonyms search box supposed to be case sensitive?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-synonyms

Is [Tags Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) search case sensitive? While the tag names are all in small letters, when I search with any capital character in the search field, it is not returning any result.

For example: when I searched with **Friday**, there is no result found.

> [image: Friday]

But when I searched with **friday**, I received the results.

> [image: friday]

In normal [Tags search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags), irrespective of the case I can get the results. So the same approach can be implemented in tags synonyms search too.

Comment: Confirmed on Skeptics SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter search will be case-insensitive starting with the next prod build. Thanks for the report!